# What's the difference between incrementing a counter once and twice

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am knew to coding and practicing on problems so I can get better. I was doing a problem on CodingBat but I got stuck on problem that I dont understand why my code isn't working.

The problem is: Given a string, return a string where for every char in the original, there are two chars.

```
doubleChar("The") → "TThhee"
doubleChar("AAbb") → "AAAAbbbb"
doubleChar("Hi-There") → "HHii--TThheerree"
```

The code I wrote was

```
public String doubleChar(String str) {
char[] STR = str.toCharArray();
      char[] two = new char[STR.length*2];
      int counter=0;
      for(int i=0;i<STR.length;i++){
          two[counter]=STR[i];
          two[counter+1]=STR[i];
          counter++;
      }
      String b= new String(two);
      return b;
}
```

[output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ2lG.png) // im guessing the counter cant increment `counter+1` but only though `counter++`. Could i get a better explanation?

After messing around it for awhile, I got it to work but I still dont understand why the original does not. I am also new to coding so I would much appreciate the help!

working:

```
public String doubleChar(String str) {
char[] STR = str.toCharArray();
      char[] two = new char[STR.length*2];
      int counter=0;
      for(int i=0;i<STR.length;i++){
          two[counter]+=STR[i];
          counter++;
          two[counter]=STR[i];
          counter++;

      }
      String b= new String(two);
      return b;
}
```

Comment: At each iteration, you write two characters, but you only increment your counter once. So first iteration writes characters 0 and 1, second iteration writes 1 and 2, third writes 2 and 3, etc. instead of 0and 1, 2 and 3, 4 and 5

Answer (score 0):

functionally,

```
counter++
```

is the same as

```
counter = counter + 1;
```

In your original code, you use the values counter and counter + 1, but you do not change the value in counter.  You only change it in the single counter++ operation, but there have to be 2 of them.  Alternatively, you could have written the following:

```
      two[counter]=STR[i]; //does NOT change the value of counter
      two[counter+1]=STR[i]; //does NOT change the value of counter
      counter += 2; //DOES change the value of counter
```

Comment: This is incorrect. it's because he is concatenating.

Comment: @Mdjon26 you're wrong. This answer is the correct one.

Comment: He is asking what is wrong with his original code, I see no concatenation there?

Answer (score 0):

In your original solution you increment your counter variable only once.

"counter + 1" doesn't increment your counter value, it's just an addition of a variable and a number (counter += 1 can increment the value of the counter variable).

So, when you write this:

```
  two[counter]=STR[i];
  two[counter+1]=STR[i];
  counter++;
```

It means (when counter = 0)

```
  two[0]=STR[i];
  two[0+1]=STR[i];
  0++; //So the value of the counter variable is still 0 here
```

And in your proper solution

```
  two[counter]+=STR[i];
  counter++;
  two[counter]=STR[i];
  counter++;
```

You increment your counter variable twice, so:

```
  two[0]+=STR[i];
  0++;
  two[1]=STR[i];
  1++;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your original:

```
counter++;
```

should be:

```
counter+=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `counter` by 2 in your original code and it works fine. Draw the output on paper:

```
for(int i=0;i<STR.length;i++){
    two[counter]=STR[i];
    two[counter+1]=STR[i];
    counter++;
}
```

For `STR = "The"`:

```
i = 0:
   counter = 0;
   two[counter] = two[0] = "T";
   two[counter+1] = two[1] = "T";

i = 1:
   counter = 1;
   two[counter] = two[1] = "h"; (You just overwrote two[1] here, it was "T" but is now "h");
   two[counter+1] = two[2] = "h";
```

etc..

Now with corrected code:

```
for(int i=0;i<STR.length;i++){
    two[counter]=STR[i];
    two[counter+1]=STR[i];
    counter+=2;
}

i = 0:
   counter = 0;
   two[counter] = two[0] = "T";
   two[counter+1] = two[1] = "T";

i = 1:
   counter = 2;
   two[counter] = two[2] = "h";
   two[counter+1] = two[3] = "h";
```